# Failed building wheel for onewire

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package, python-wheel

For a small python project, I'm need to include the "onewire" package.
I tried to install it with

```
pip install onewire
```

I then get a huge error message, that includes:

```
Failed building wheel for onewire
Running setup-py clean for onewire ... error
```

([Full picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G65w3.png) Sorry, I couldn't copy/paste it because it's all written on one line...)

I already tried:

```
pip install wheel
```

which didn't work. Also, I've tried to install it via the PyCharm Packages installer which resulted in the same error message.

I use the following versions:

- Python 3.8.2
- Pip 20.2.2

I also updated my visual studio installations

- [(Picture) Visual Studio Installations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TU5S.png)
- [(Picture) Visual Studio 2017 Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxZ1Z.png)
- [(Picture) Visual Studio 2019 Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv69W.png)

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you upgrade your pip? `pip install -upgrade pip` and your `setop-tools`.

Comment: Yes, it's all up to date.

Comment: Can you attach a picture of the error you are getting?

Comment: done. sorry I forgot it before

Comment: The issue seems to be with wheel building onewire but it does not use PEP 427. You would require the `build tools for Visual Studio`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need build tools for Visual Studio to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.

1. [Download it from here.](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)
2. When you begin the installer, it will have several "options" enabled which will balloon the install size to 5gb. If you have Windows 10, you'll need to leave selected the "Windows 10 SDK" option.
3. Since, the current link to the build tool directs to the Visual Studio 2017, you'd also need to these:

A. VC++ 2017 version xx.x tools

B. Windows SDK to use standard libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed the tools and updated Visual Studio. However, it didn't change anything. I attached the pictures of my visual studio configurations for you to check.